# How to display text and image side by side in column of a table in html

Tags: html, css

I have a table in whose column I show both a image and text.Image is being displayed on upper side and text is being displayed below it.But I want to show both side by side.Moreover I want table to be fit on screen i.e I don't want to have scroll bars.

My Html code is

```js
<% @page language = "java"
contentType = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding = "ISO-8859-1" %>
  <% @taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
prefix = "c" %>
  <% @taglib prefix = "fmt"
uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
  < !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" >
< html >
  < head >
  < meta http - equiv = "refresh"
content = "30" >
  < title > Insert title here < /title>
<style>


    .green {
        color: green;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    
       
       
      
    }

    .red    {
        color: red;
      
       text-transform: capitalize;
      
      
}

</div >
  < /style>
</head >

  < body style = 'margin:0;padding:0;' >

  < jsp: useBean id = "bs"
class = "beam_Status.BeamStatus_Bean" >

  < /jsp:useBean>


 <div id="loadData">

<CENTER><H1>BEAMLINE STATUS</H1 > < /CENTER>
<center>
<table  border = "1"  width="100%" height="60"> 

     <tr> 
      <th><h1><b>BEAMLINES</b > < /h1></th >
  < th > < h1 > < b > STATUS < /b></h1 > < /th> 
       
    </tr >

  < c: forEach
var = "country"
items = "${bs.beam_CurrentStatus()}" >
  < h3 > < b >
  < c: choose >
  < c: when test = "${country.value == 'IN OPERATION'}" >
  < tr >
  < td class = "green"
style = "text-transform: uppercase;" > < center > < h2 > $ {
    country.key
  } < /h2></center > < /td> 
                <td class="green" style="text-transform: uppercase; "  ><img style="vertical-align:middle;" src = "red.png" height="50" width="50"   / > < h2 > $ {
    country.value
  } < /h2></td >

  < /tr> 
   </c: when >
  < c: otherwise >
  < tr >
  < td class = "red"
style = "text-transform: uppercase; " > < center > < h2 > $ {
    country.key
  } < /h2></center > < /td> 
               <td class="red"  style="text-transform: uppercase; " ><img style="vertical-align:middle;" src = "green.png" height="50" width="50"  / > < h2 > $ {
    country.value
  } < /h2> </td >

  < /tr> 
  </c: otherwise >
  < /c:choose>
</b > < /h3>
    </c: forEach >

  < /table>
 
</center >
  < /div>
 <script>
 
  < /html >
```

[image]

My output.

I want the second column text and image to be aligned side by side and table to fit the screen.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code posted is not HTML at all. Show the actual HTML code (unless the method of generating it is crucial, in which case explain why and tag the question appropriately). Moreover, the code seems to take extra measures to *prevent* the image and the text appearing side by side, so you should explain what needs to be preserved of the existing code,

Answer (score 2):

Got it, just added

> display: inline-block

```
<h2 style="vertical-align:middle; display: inline-block;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simpler to break the column with image and text in 2 distinct columns: 1 for the image and 1 for the text. In css you can use: table {width:100%}

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in the image tag:

add `display:block` and add `float:left`

In the text to show it side by side, just add `float:left` assuming text is inside a block element like a p tag.

For table to occupy full screen use `width:100%;`

Comment: ,I have alredy done width:100%. But the table height is not fitting on screen.On right side scroll bar appaers